# renaming discount coupon in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, discount, localisation

Please let me know how to rename " Discount Coupons " in the checkout Page. I want to rename to " Discount vouches/ first 5 digits of your card "

Comment: you can get the phtml file from code hinting and alter according to ur text

Answer (score 3):

**Don't change texts in the `phtml` templates, use translation instead.**

Turn on template hints to find out, in which templates the texts are translated. Then look into the template and find out which module is used for translation. It should be something like:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Discount Coupons')
```

In this example, the module is `Mage_Checkout`. If you find `$this->__('Discount Coupons')` instead, the module is derived from the block class (which again you can see in the template hints).

### How to change the translation

1. Open the file `app/design/[your_package]/[your_theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv` or create it if it does not exist.
2. Add this line:

   ```
    "Mage_Checkout::Discount Coupons","Discount vouches/ first 5 digits of your card"
   ```

This will tell Magento to use `"Discount vouches/ first 5 digits of your card"` instead of `"Discount Coupons"` everywhere in the `Mage_Checkout` module.

---

Alternatively you can use the inline translation feature, as explained here: http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/ - this will store your changed translations in the database instead.

It's easy to use but you cannot search for the texts in the code base anymore and it's harder to migrate/deploy the translations to another system. So I prefer using translation files but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it from below file.

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\coupon.phtml

   <h2><?php echo $this->__('Discount vouches/ first 5 digits of your card') ?></h2>
   <div class="discount-form">
   <label for="coupon_code"><?php echo $this->__('Enter your coupon code if you have one.') ?></label>
```

Hope you know how to enable the template path hinting from the admin panel

```
system->configuration->Developer->Debug->Template Path Hints(choose yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the template hints and find out the template name from where the Discount coupon code is coming from.

Once you find the file name you just need to rename the String "Discount Coupons" to "Discount vouches/ first 5 digits of your card"

Before renaming just make sure you are not editing the core file.if the code is coming from the core file just copy the file to your theme and change there.

for enabling the template path hints you can refer this link http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints[enter link description here](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)